# Maintaining URL structure while restoring

Tags: php, url, switch-statement

I need to restore a site from archives while maintaining the exact URL structure. I'm done with all the pages, the only thing remaining is to get the URL's correct and I need your help.

The URL is in the following format, wwwDOTmypagehere.com/?en

Where en points to the english version of the website.

I figured out do it using a variable like, wwwDOTmypagehere.com/?id=en, but how do I get rid of the need to have a variable there ?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With `htaccess`, you can redirect `?en` to `?id=en` in the background, without displaying it in the status bar of the browser. Something like this should work:

```
RewriteRule ^\?([a-z]+)$ ?id=$1 [NC]
```

Or if you want to do it with PHP, then you should check, which `$_GET` element exists from your languages. So for example `wwwDOTmypagehere.com/?en` will create a `$_GET['en']` key with a 0 length string value. So this way, you don't need the `id` key.

Comment: I going to need a little explanation about that. However, it would be great if it could be using php code.

Comment: I have added to the post, how it can be done with PHP. I hope it is clear.